# Can I return a java object from spark UDF using java

Tags: java, apache-spark

How can I return a java object from a spark java udf.
I am able to return the spark datatypes but unable to return any java object

Comment: post code/sample data you tried and you are expecting. single liners are considererd to be low quality posts in SO

Answer (score 0):

You can return a complex object from spark UDF, but you need to define custom data type when registering it to spark session. Check this...

[How to return complex types using spark UDFs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750540/how-to-return-complex-types-using-spark-udfs)